# How do I convert graphQL query result into data array

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am migrating from redux to graphQL and using Apollo 2.1 with React. I would like to convert query result from json format into an array.

If my Query return is something like this {x: x, y:y, z:z}, can I modify the return to look something like this [x,y,z]? This is obviously easy to do in a separate function but trying to come up to speed on graphQL.

Comment: Just get the keys or values as you need using `Object.keys(..)` or `Object.values(..)`..

Comment: Do you mean in a separate function? Was hoping to do this in the Query itself if that is possible so that I only have to do the transformation one time.